# Difference between .getPath() vs cursor in getting the real path of a file from uri in Android

Tags: android

The main idea of the question is just same as the title - what is the difference between .getPath() vs cursor, when you get the real path of a file from uri in Android?

In case you don't get what I meant by using cursor, the example is here.

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    String result;
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
        result = contentURI.getPath();
    } else { 
        cursor.moveToFirst(); 
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
        result = cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

The two most frequent ways were these two, but it seems a bit too complicated using cursor, while you can get the same result with one simple method, .getPath(). So, I think there must be the reason I should use the cursor in some cases, but I can't get it.

Could you explain me what it would be?

Answer (score 6):

> what is the difference between .getPath() vs cursor, when you get the real path of a file from uri in Android?

A `Uri` is not a file. There is no "real path".

*If* the scheme of the `Uri` is `file`, *then* it represents a file on the filesystem that, in theory, your app should be able to access. Use `getPath()` to get the filesystem path.

If the scheme is anything else, it does not necessarily represent a file on the filesystem that your app can access. For example, if the scheme is `http` or `https`, the `Uri` represents something that would be downloaded from a Web server.

If the scheme is `content`, then it is backed by a `ContentProvider`. Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`.

*If* the scheme is `content` *and* you specifically obtained the `Uri` from the `MediaStore`, *then* perhaps your `Cursor` approach will give you a path. It also might give you `null`, and the path that you get may not be accessible to you (just because the system's `MediaStore` can index a file does not imply that your app has access to that same file). This is worse on Android 10, where you do not have read access to external storage by default. Hence, this technique is unreliable and should not be used.

Beyond that, though, you cannot make any assumptions about what data is used to support that `content` `Uri`. It could be:

- A local file on external storage
- A local file on internal storage for the other app (e.g., served by `FileProvider`)
- A local file on removable storage
- A local file that is encrypted and needs to be decrypted on the fly by the `ContentProvider`
- A stream of bytes held in a `BLOB` column in a database that needs to be served by the `ContentProvider`
- A piece of content that needs to be downloaded by the other app first (e.g., Dropbox)
- ...and so on

So, to recap: a `Uri` is not a file. There is no "real path".