# How to get path from given URI in android

Tags: android, file, android-camera, android-10.0

When we select an image from download folder then find URI like this

> *content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A27*

but when we try to get real path from this uri then we cont get real path.
This issue is face from only android 10 version emulater and some redmi mobile.
I am try many method and technik but cont solve.

we have check these below URL but not working in my case:

[Android Kotlin: Getting a FileNotFoundException with filename chosen from file picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59123162/android-kotlin-getting-a-filenotfoundexception-with-filename-chosen-from-file-p)

[create-a-file-from-a-photo-uri-on-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56308559/create-a-file-from-a-photo-uri-on-android)

[difference-between-getpath-vs-cursor-in-getting-the-real-path-of-a-file-from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54843895/difference-between-getpath-vs-cursor-in-getting-the-real-path-of-a-file-from)

[android-get-real-path-of-a-txt-file-selected-from-the-file-explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49221312/android-get-real-path-of-a-txt-file-selected-from-the-file-explorer)

My Code is :

```
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}
```

And getting below Error:

```
  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "msf:27"
```

Any Suggesition how to get real path from download folder image.

Comment: @Desto's question is valid. This error `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "msf:27"` is unresolved yet.

Comment: @MMK Hi, is there any update on it, how did you fixed this issue ?

Comment: @MMK I have resolved the issue and posted answer here for msf: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62154537/2024527

Comment: @MMK I have resolved this problem.

Comment: @Abhinavsingh how you resolved?

Comment: I have resolved my problem

Comment: @Abhinavsingh how did you solve this. Please post your answer.

Comment: Try This. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68827976/15342371